# "X does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#

I have a class called `Enemy` beneath class `Program` (which is the class that has `Main`):

```
abstract public class Enemy
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int baseHealth { get; set; }
    public int baseAttackDamage { get; set; }
    public int baseMagicDamage { get; set; }
    public int level { get; set; }
    public int baseMoneyDropped { get; set; }
    public string damageType { get; set; }

    public int GenerateEnemyLevel()
    {
        Random genEnemyLevelModifier = new Random();
        int getEnemyLevel = genEnemyLevelModifier.Next(-3, 3) + player.level;
        return(getEnemyLevel);
    }
}
```

The problem with this code, is that it says

> player, in player.level does not exist in the current context.

Here's the `player` instance within `Main`, and the `Player` class above the `Enemy` class.

```
//Player decleration
Player player = new Player();
player.level = 1;
player.id = 1
```

Player class:

```
public class Player
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string currentClass { get; set; }
    public int level { get; set; }
    public int experience { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: While researching your question, can you tell us what other solutions you found and how your situation differs from theirs?

Comment: Try clicking on `Player` and hitting Ctrl + . (period)

Comment: you have missing player object to enemy class

Comment: Variables declared in `Main` are locals, not global. You can't expect to access them from anywhere else without passing them or making them class-level fields.

Comment: I don't understand the votes to close and the downvotes. This is a legitimate question from someone who's trying to learn.

Answer (score 3):

`Player` doesn't exist in this context:

```
public int GenerateEnemyLevel()
{
        Random genEnemyLevelModifier = new Random();
        int getEnemyLevel = genEnemyLevelModifier.Next(-3, 3) + player.level;
        return(getEnemyLevel);
}
```

You're trying to set a property of an object, but all you have is a `Player` class that hasn't been instantiated.

In object oriented programming, you're working with instances of classes (known as objects.) In this case, you do not have an instance of `Player`.

Instead, consider making your code look like this:

```
public int GenerateEnemyLevel(Player player)
{
        Random genEnemyLevelModifier = new Random();
        int getEnemyLevel = genEnemyLevelModifier.Next(-3, 3) + player.level;
        return(getEnemyLevel);
}
```

and you would then pass in the instance of your `Player` class to the method.

For example:

```
Player p = new Player();

GenerateEnemyLevel(p);
```

Edit -

A more detailed answer to an approach that could work. I'm not sure why you're using an abstract class, but you could consider something similar to the following:

```
abstract public class Enemy
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int baseHealth { get; set; }
    public int baseAttackDamage { get; set; }
    public int baseMagicDamage { get; set; }
    public int level { get; set; }
    public int baseMoneyDropped { get; set; }
    public string damageType { get; set; }
    public Player player { get; set;}

    public Enemy()
    {
        player = new Player();
    }

    public int GenerateEnemyLevel()
    {
        Random genEnemyLevelModifier = new Random();
        int getEnemyLevel = genEnemyLevelModifier.Next(-3, 3) + player.level;
        return(getEnemyLevel);
    }
}
```

By adding the method `Enemy` to your abstract class, you've created a constructor. This runs at the time that the object is instantiated. Note that you can't instantiate an abstract directly, you need to establish some sort level of inheritance such as an implementation similar to this:

```
public class BadGuy : Enemy
{
}
```

So if you're not wanting to get that deep into things this early on, I'd suggest removing the abstract keyword for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the explanation and even the example. This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @asmit10 no problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your abstract Enemy class doesn't have any reference to `player`.  Just pass the instance it should work

```
   public int GenerateEnemyLevel(Player player)
        {
            Random genEnemyLevelModifier = new Random();
            int getEnemyLevel = genEnemyLevelModifier.Next(-3, 3) + player.level;
            return (getEnemyLevel);
        }
```